# How high can I build a privacy screen on my deck?

Tags: deck, post

I am replacing decking and would like to replace the guard on one side with a taller structure, about 18' long for privacy.  Originally the intent was to reduce noise from a noisy neighbor but the plan morphed to a privacy screen because of concern that a tall, solid structure (basically a fence attached to the deck) would not withstand high winds.  We are in the midwest and rarely get gusts to 60 MPH.

The old guards are being removed as the deck is low enough they are not required and also they are notched 4x4s lag bolted to the outside of the rim joist - not something I would want to try and use to build higher.  The plan is to mount 4x4 posts inside the rim joist with 4x blocking, structural screws etc as has been posted elsewhere referencing the Simpson Strong tie site.
My question is, I know this is a preferred method for attaching posts for a standard guardrail but will this hold up to a taller more solid structure?  How tall could I go, and could a stockade type solid screen work or would it be safer to use a shadowbox design?  How far apart should the posts be?
Not an engineer but I've tried to do some calculations on the wind load vs shear strength of the hardware I'm using so if anyone has some assistance in that area that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can any braces be added to other walls, or must the wall/screen stand by itself?

Comment: How **tall** - you mention 18 feet long, but no height. I'd tend to think that rater than anything "attached to the rim joist" setting the posts directly in the ground (or setting post bases with appropriate attaching hardware in the ground and attaching the posts to them) would be both sturdier and not risk the deck structure.

Comment: I added 6' privacy fence to a  deck before. There is no amount of bracing that will stop sway without going into ground too. Even then there will be some movement and precautions need to be done to stop squeaking, bolts, screws, nails from failing over time .

Comment: Depending on your local area, you may run afoul of "fence height restrictions" if you go too high, so look into that before you worry too much about building an absurdly tall fence. You might be forced to cut it shorter.

Comment: I was hoping for 6 feet but even 5 would be an improvement.  Really haven't come up with any alternatives.  Our region requires footers to be 38" deep and I can't see how I could realistically dig those under the existing deck frame.  I don't want a separate fence outside the deck area for several reasons.   I was concerned this was not feasible but at the same time I see these Hoft systems that are basically just fastened through the deck surface into the beams or blocks and they look like they would be much more unstable.

Comment: I can't attach it to anything else.  It would be attached only to the deck joints and blocking.

Comment: If you have the deck surface off so you can put the new posts in, you can use a posthole digger (manual or powered.)

Comment: You dont have to go 3' deep with post but go as deep as you can  under deck.  All privacy fences sway in the wind. Decks are not meant to sway. Over time the fence could cause damage to deck.  Use thrubolts or carriage bolts when possible. Lags, screws, structural screws will loosen over time.. Keep spacing under 6'.  You  may need diagonal bracing from footing post to beam to stop whole deck from swaying.